# writing a list to a txt file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

list consists of RANDOM strings inside it

```
#example
list = [1,2,3,4]

filename = ('output.txt')
outfile = open(filename, 'w')
outfile.writelines(list)
outfile.close()
```

my result in the file

```
1234
```

so now how do I make the program produce the result that I want which is:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: What are these indentation for? list does not contain any string at all

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
myList = [1,2,3,4]

with open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
  outfile.write('\n'.join(str(i) for i in myList))
```

By the way, the list that you have in your post contains `int`s, not strings.
Also, please NEVER name your variables `list` or `dict` or any other type for that matter

Comment: names like `list_` and `dict_` are fine though

Answer (score 2):

`writelines()` needs a `list` of strings with line separators appended to them but your code is only giving it a list of integers. To make it work you'd need to use something like this:

```
some_list = [1,2,3,4]

filename = 'output.txt'
outfile = open(filename, 'w')
outfile.writelines([str(i)+'\n' for i in some_list])
outfile.close()
```

In Python file objects are [context managers](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) which means they can be used with a `with` statement so you could do the same thing a little more succinctly with the following which will close the file automatically. It also uses a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator%20expression#generator-expressions) (enclosed in parentheses instead of brackets) to do the string conversion since doing that avoids the need to build a temporary list just to pass to the function.

```
with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines((str(i)+'\n' for i in some_list))
```